# Errors in PrefsLoadTask (Tutorial #13 ver.38)

Tags: java, android, commonsware

I get the following 3 errors in the ModelFragment.java:

```
The method doInBackGround(Context...) of type ModelFragment.PrefsLoadTask must override      or implement a supertype method

The type ModelFragment.PrefsLoadTask must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<Context,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Context...)   

Void methods cannot return a value
```

Here is my sourcecode:

```
private class PrefsLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
    SharedPreferences localPrefs=null;

    @Override
    protected void doInBackGround(Context... ctxt) {
        localPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctxt[0]);
        localPrefs.getAll();

        return(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void Arg0) {
        ModelFragment.this.prefs=localPrefs;
        ModelFragment.this.prefsTask=null;
        deliverModel();
    }
}
```

As far as i can see the code is just like in the book. Also i have gone through all code that i have entered in this chapter. Can you see any errors her? The apps run ok after step #5 in this chapter.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as i can see the code is just like in the book

No, it is not. It is `doInBackground()`, not `doInBackGround()` (notice the case of the `g`). Also, the return type must be `Void`, not `void` (notice the case of the `V`).

Comment: Sorry. This case sensivity is new for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Sjubussen: Java is case-sensitive for just about everything -- sorry!